# How to Enable Wordwrap on Description in Grid (XUL)

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, dtd

In my `xul` file, I have a simple scheme:

```
<tabpanel>
    <vbox>
        <description>&spat.options.label.text;</description>
        <grid>
            <columns>
                <column/>
                <column flex="2"/>
            </columns>
            <rows>              
                <row>
                    <label.../>
                </row>
            </rows>
        </grid>
    </vbox>
</tabpanel>
```

The dtd entity brings in a very long string of text.

I can't seem to get any sort of wordwrap on the text in the description.

If I move the description out of the tabpanel, it will wrap fine.  But if it is in the tabpanel, it gets cut off (truncated).  I tried the same in a grid *without* a tabpanel, but had the same problem.

How can I get wordwrap in the description?

Comment: I guess, it's clearly explainned here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/description

Comment: Well, it is *almost* clear.  I've reread that page over several times already.  The description wrap works fine if it is not inside of a box.  It never says explicitly that if you put it in a `box` that it won't wrap unless you assign a width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one solution is to add a `width` property for the `<description>` tag in the css.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<box orient="{*horizontal | vertical}">
<description id="desc" style="width: 300px"></description>
<script type="application/x-javascript">
<![CDATA[
document.getElementById('desc').textContent = "This is a long section of dynamic message text that will word wrap";
]]>
</script>
</box>
</window>
```

[image]
///`I don't want to claim this as a solution, just to give an exmaple,i have posted this`////